# How to add multiple data to one string value in regedit

Tags: windows, windows-registry, regedit

I need to add **two URL's to a single string value** in registry. Please guide me which separator needs to be added to this two URL? I cannot add another string value with same name since it wont accept it. kindly help me out. Thanks in advance. attached screenshot for your reference.

[image: Screenshot for reference]

I have Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Registry's native functionality for storing multiple strings requires that the [value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) be **REG_MULTI_SZ**, not the REG_SZ that your value is currently using.

If your application will work with the REG_MULTI_SZ value type, change it as follows:

1. Rename the existing value to **URL-old**
2. Right-click the white space below the values and click **New** then **Multi-String Value**
3. Name the value (`URL` in your case)
4. Edit the value and on each separate line provide the various strings you require
5. Delete the original **URL-old** value once you've transferred all of the strings

---

It's of course possible your application expects multiple strings to be stored in a value with the REG_SZ type. If this is a case, the correct delimiter will be specified by the application.  *Common* delimiters include the characters `;`, `|` (pipe), and `,`, but it's anybody's guess what the application expects.

There is no standard delimiter for separating strings in Registry data since that functionality is provided by the REG_MULTI_SZ value type.

Comment: I do added reg multi sz as you suggested. but when i restart the system and check its automatically changing to reg sz type and only first value is added. could you help me what would be the cause for that?

Comment: It appears your application doesn't support the REG_MULTI_SZ value type. You should contact the application vendor to find out how to provide multiple strings through the one Registry value.