# Disable Windows + Tab Without downloading anything

Tags: windows-10

I read this post at https://superuser.com/a/1330717/1077289 about how to disable Windows + Tab. I did everything correctly, I think:
[image: screenshot]

Now, when I put "Tab" into the Value data, it seems to interpret it was "T A B"
 and not the key "Tab." Is there any way to put "Tab" into there so it disables Windows + Tab. (I've tried it with other shortcuts. I put "R" into the Value Data section, it it successfully disabled Windows + R, but it doesn't work when I put "Tab" in there).

Comment: I experimented with `'tab'` and `"tab"` but no Registry values I tried allowed Windows to recognize the `Tab`key. Hopefully someone else knows a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The "DisabledHotkeys" registry key won't work in Windows 10 to disable WIN+TAB.  I've tried all suggested ways to get just that one shortcut disabled and nothing I've seen works.

A mod on the MS community says it's not possible:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/how-to-disable-wintab-hotkeys/3de357d6-cb00-47cb-ba78-d7d3b0f45c86?auth=1

I know you've specified "without downloading anything", but the only way I could find to do this was using Microsoft's latest PowerToys release.  I don't have the reputation to answer the question that doesn't have the "without downloading" restriction.  PowerToys is Microsoft software so you know it's safe.

Search for "microsoft powertoys" and you'll get their github URL:

https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys

Make sure you let it start on Startup during the installation.

Once installed, open its settings and select "Keyboard Manager".  Click "Remap a shortcut".  In the window that opens, click the "+" button, then click the "Type" button under "Shortcut:". Hit WIN+TAB and click okay.  Under "Mapped to:", click the dropdown and select a key that doesn't exist on your keyboard.  I chose "F24".  Leave "All Apps" for the "Target App" and click the big OK button at the top and you no longer have to worry about WIN+TAB doing anything.

Since I wanted to disable it because I was accidentally hitting WIN+TAB when trying to hit ALT+TAB, I ended up mapping WIN+TAB to ALT+TAB. EDIT: This turned out to be a bad idea. Was fun to see what happened when trying to use the arrow keys while holding the WIN key after WIN+TAB, though. :)

Here's the related question, for reference: [Windows 10 disable Win + Tab Task View shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/1330698/windows-10-disable-win-tab-task-view-shortcut?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

**Disable TAB key only**

Navigate to the following key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout
```

In right-side pane, **right-click** on the empty space and select **New**

```
Binary Value
```

Rename the newly created entry as

```
Scancode Map
```

and set its value to

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
02 00 00 00 00 00 0F 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Restart your computer

Comment: Would this also disable Alt + Tab? I only want to disable Windows + Tab since I still use Alt + Tab

Comment: Yes it will disable Alt + Tab. I will try research more but it will take time, I had to figure that out myself from when you posted