# How to change the Windows key + Tab key combination in Windows 10 to mouse button

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

In Windows 10 upon pressing the key with Windows logo on it and the Tab key together, I get an overview of all the open windows. I would like to access this functionality by one of the buttons on my mouse. How can I change this key combination to one of the buttons on my mouse?

Comment: Probably a third party package like Autohotkey to do all that you want,

Comment: The hotkey is Alt+Tab and it does much more than just display the overview.

Comment: @harrymc, **both** Win+Tab and Alt+Tab are useful preview key combos, but they perform differently. The question asked about Win+Tab is correct as-is.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Win+Tab doesn't work on my Windows 10.

Comment: @harrymc, see https://superuser.com/questions/1330698/windows-10-disable-win-tab-task-view-shortcut . It might be specifically disabled on your PC. It does work on this 21H1 (build 19043.1736) machine. Admittedly, MS is not known for total consistency... ;-)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Nope, don't have any of this.

Answer (score 0):

A utility such as [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/x_mouse_button_control.html), or an [alternative tool](https://alternativeto.net/software/x-mouse-button-control/), can translate a mouse button click into a a key-press combo, whether <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>. Perhaps [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), can as well.