# VMWare Fusion: stop Command + Tab being sent to Windows 10 client?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-fusion

I have a problem with the Apple <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcut key, and I don't really think that combination of characters should be sent to the VM.

I'm running a mac mini i7 on MacOS 12.6.4 (21G526) with a Windows 10 22H2 VM, and when I press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> Windows pops up with a 'multi-task' window, and shows virtual desktops and all this sort of stuff.

All I want is to see the MacOS Task selector and not have Windows do stupid things.
So, how do I disable sending the <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>) shortcut to the Windows 10 VM and triggering this extra 'feature' in Windows?

I tried adding a key mapping, but I can't set a key mapping to a `null` entry, and so I'm a bit lost as to what to do.

I'm running VMWare Fusion 13.0.2 and it's driving me crazy.

Comment: What's with the random edits? I'd prefer an answer over minor text formatting please.

Comment: Might be relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/1330698/windows-10-disable-win-tab-task-view-shortcut

Comment: I wish it was. I think Fusion needs an option to stop sending those key combinations I think, 'cause it breaks the COMMAND-TAB task switching in MacOS.

Comment: And, the problem is that sometimes it does it, and other times it doesn't. It's inconsistent which makes it even more frustrating.